# How can I remove method name from URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am using the multilingual feature in my Codeigniter website. 
current URL looks like

```
http://example.com/hi/news/view/news-title
```

I want this like

```
http://example.com/hi/news/news-title
```

current routes.php is looking like

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


//Routes for multilingual url
$route['^hi/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "$1";

// '/en' -> use default controller
$route['^hi$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

.htaccess file looks like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried these but it not works and always give me 404 error

```
$route['^(en|hi)/news/(:any)'] = "news/view/$1"; 

$route['hi/news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the name of the controller or the controller called "News" is not exists.

Specify the name of the controller that is having the "news" method e.g.

```
$route['(en|hi)/news/(:any)'] = "home/news/view/$1";
```

OR

Create a "News" controller and create a "view" method e.g.

```
class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function view()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: news is the controller name and view is the function name.